# Alternative Download for iOS 6 Simulator?

Tags: ios, ios-simulator

I just installed Xcode 4.6.1 from the App Store.  However, I get a Network timeout error when I try to download any of the Xcode->Preferences->Downloads->Components.  I was able to download the "Command Line Tools" from Apple's developer site (I don't have any difficulties downloading via Safari).  However, I was unable to find an alternative iOS 6 Simulator download.

Is there an alternative download location for the iOS 6 Simulator? 
If so, where can I find it?

Answer (score 1):

Possibly try to download the simulators on a different connection? I have never heard of this issue, and doubt that apples servers are down for downloading such content. If the issues persists connect to a different network.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, but I have no other connections available.  I also have problems accessing  ML help content, which Apples says is due to our satellite ISP.  I don't know if this is related or not.  Perhaps I'll try again early tomorrow morning to see whether that helps.

Comment: I tried again later and it finally downloaded okay.  Just FYI, when the problem occurred, the files would start to download, but would then get the network timeout error.  For example, I repeatedly got around 37% of the "Command Lie Tools" before it would get the error.  Also, a lot of folks with a satellite ISP have the problem accessing ML help content.  I'll have to find my help either in books or online.

Comment: Yea sorry to hear that. If you dont mind me asking what ISP do you have? Just curious thats all.

Comment: I am using HughesNet Gen4 Satellite with their provided HT1000 modem.  We are too far away from the station for DSL and there is no Cable (not even for TV) in our area.